# Putting the Log in Page in the Home Page

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm a total newbie to JHipster and I wanted to know if there's a way to "merge" the login page into to the home page of JHipster.
So far, my HTML looks like this :

[image: 1]

But once I merge both of the codes of the `login.component.ts` and the `home.component.ts`. It looks like this:

[image: 2]

I don't really know what went wrong, and I have no errors whatsoever.
my `home.component.ts` looks like this :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy,AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginModalService } from 'app/core/login/login-modal.service';
import { AccountService } from 'app/core/auth/account.service';
import { Account } from 'app/core/user/account.model';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from 'app/core/login/login.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.scss'],

})
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit ,OnInit, OnDestroy {
  account: Account | null = null;
  authSubscription?: Subscription;
  @ViewChild('username', { static: false })
  username?: ElementRef;

  authenticationError = false;

  loginForm = this.fb.group({
    username: [''],
    password: [''],
    rememberMe: [false],
  });

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private loginModalService: LoginModalService,private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.username) {
      this.username.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  cancel(): void {
    this.authenticationError = false;
    this.loginForm.patchValue({
      username: '',
      password: '',
    });
    this.activeModal.dismiss('cancel');
  }

  login(): void {
    this.loginService
      .login({
        username: this.loginForm.get('username')!.value,
        password: this.loginForm.get('password')!.value,
        rememberMe: this.loginForm.get('rememberMe')!.value,
      })
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          this.authenticationError = false;
          this.activeModal.close();
          if (
            this.router.url === '/account/register' ||
            this.router.url.startsWith('/account/activate') ||
            this.router.url.startsWith('/account/reset/')
          ) {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
          }
        },
        () => (this.authenticationError = true)
      );
  }

  register(): void {
    this.activeModal.dismiss('to state register');
    this.router.navigate(['/account/register']);
  }

  requestResetPassword(): void {
    this.activeModal.dismiss('to state requestReset');
    this.router.navigate(['/account/reset', 'request']);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authSubscription = this.accountService.getAuthenticationState().subscribe(account => (this.account = account));
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.accountService.isAuthenticated();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.authSubscription) {
      this.authSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a mistake in my code? Thanks

Comment: What is the goal your are trying to achieve? Just get rid of the login modal or only allow access to the application after logged in? How does you home.component.html look like? Are you sure you have not errors in the browsers javascript console?

Comment: I kinda figured it out, the problem was coming from the NgbActiveModal.
Thanks for taking the time to answer me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it, the problem was coming from NgbActiveModal, we just didn't have to initialize it in the home constructor and everything worked out fine !